# Call runOnUiThread from another thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I need to wait some period of time(10 seconds) and after this I must redraw canvas. I used [Handler#postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) for measure time period. My code (just section):

```
handler.postDelayed(updates, 10000);

private Runnable updates = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        methodToRedraw();
    }
};

public void methodToRedraw(){
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       // redraw canvas
    }
 });
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't know if this is correct, but it was my only solution. Maybe someone can help or know better solution. I would be thankful.

PS. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Where are you creating the handler that you're posting to? Is it created in an Activity? If so, you don't need the runOnUiThread call as the Handler is already running on the UI Thread.

Comment: @twaddington is right. If you create the handler in your main thread, the posted methods will run in the ui thread. If you are using runOnUiThread, you probably don't need a handler.

Comment: Yes, I created handler in Activity. So in this case runnable updates will be run on UI thread?

Comment: @mainmilly that is correct. You don't necessarily have to change your code, but in this case the call to runOnUiThread is redundant. According to the Handler documentation: "When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it": http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Answer (score -1):

You could use AsyncTask as well. Let Android handles thread creation...

```
protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls){Thread.sleep(10000);}
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {methodToRedraw();}
```